# XSL-FO - Scaling image inside a table

Tags: image, scale, xsl-fo

This table is inside another table.  Why is the image not scaling to 1 inch?

```
         <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.00in" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="url('{$url}')" scaling="uniform" scaling-method="auto" width="1.00in"/>                                       
                                </fo:block>  
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>                                                 
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to specify the **content-width** attribute in external-graphic.